# Finding center in random data based on adjacent points

Tags: algorithm, points

Say I am giving a 2D array which contains black and white pixels.
I want to find the "center" or the datapoints based on the adjacent pixels.
That means the most dense parts have the highest impact, and small loose/scatterd/thinly only have a small impact.

Here is a sample images for my use case:

[image: Sample1]

What is the best algorithm in this scenario to find the center?

Comment: The graph you showed us has a bit of a shotgun blast appearance.  The center, with the red x, is the most dense, and density then decreases, at some rate, going in any direction from that center point outward.  Would the patterns you need to evaluate _always_ have this distribution?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right. I updated my post with some pictures from my input data.

Comment: Brute force: Divide up the image on a 2D grid, and then take density measurements at each grid point, by sampling very closely around each point.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you mean by "dense" and "center". There is the "connected" property in computer graphics which requires a definition of neighbourhood and several measures for point clouds to produce some kind of center (e.g. center-of-gravity, center of enclosing circle, mean of center of polygon outline, etc.). Moreover, you will need to find a sensible function to produce the weight for the single regions, which doesn't counteract your intended function - not easy in reality.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I am not sure how to explain it. In the sample image provided the "center" would refer to the center point of the black line. Because the line is more dense then the nois eon the left and right. So the center point would be moved slightly to the right from the middle of the image.

Comment: For curiosity, if the sample image is a black circle (white around, black circle, white insite, like a O) center will be the center of circle?

Comment: Yes, if the density of the pixel of the circle is the same everywhere, then yes. @Cid

Answer (score 1):

The following function calculates the weighted center of a given image.
The image is represented as an array of boolean. Black is represented as 'true' and white as 'false'.

```
double[] weightedCenter(boolean[][] img){
    int W = img.length;
    int H = img[0].length;
    double centerX = 0;
    double centerY = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<W;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<H;j++){
            if(!img[i][j])
                continue;
            centerX += nbs(img, i, j) * i;
            centerY += nbs(img, i, j) * j;
        }
    }
    centerX /= (W * H);
    centerY /= (W * H);
    return new double[]{centerX, centerY};
}
```

The weight for each black pixel is calculated(as requested) based on the number of immediate black neighbours.

```
double nbs(boolean[][] img, int x, int y){
    int W = img.length;
    int H = img[0].length;
    int[] offset = {-1, 0, 1};
    double nb0 = 0;
    double nb1 = 0;
    for(int xOff : offset){
        for(int yOff : offset){
            int x2 = x + xOff;
            int y2 = y + yOff;
            if(x2 < 0 || x2 >= W || y2 < 0 || y2 >= H)
                continue;
            nb0++;
            if(img[x2][y2])
                nb1++;
        }
    }
    return nb1 / nb0;
}
```